# How to add arrows to an infinite line?

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I'm graphing part of a parabola, like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \clip (-0.1,-0.1) rectangle (4,3);
        \draw[->] (0,0) -- (4,0);
        \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,3);% draw axis lines
        \draw[domain=0.1:2,red,->,thick,samples=400] plot ({\x},{\x^3} );% draw plot
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

As you see, I'm trying to put an arrowhead onto the upward end of the parabola line, but it's not happening. I hypothesize that it's because the line is infinite, so there's no end to put an arrowhead on. Is that right? And in any case, is there a way to put an arrowhead on to that line?

Comment: The arrow was clipped (outside clipping box). Enlarge the clipping box, or shorten the domain to say `0.1:1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the TeX grouping braces are the source of error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \clip (-0.1,-0.1) rectangle (4,3);
        \draw[->] (0,0) -- (4,0);
        \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,3);% draw axis lines
  %      \draw[domain=0.1:2,red,->,thick,samples=400] plot ({\x},{\x^3} );% draw plot
\draw[domain=0.1:2,red,->,thick,samples=400] plot (\x,\x^3 );% draw plot
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If you choose:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \clip (-0.1,-0.1) rectangle (4,3);
        \draw[->] (0,0) -- (4,0);
        \draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,3);% draw axis lines
  %      \draw[domain=0.1:2,red,->,thick,samples=400] plot ({\x},{\x^3} );% draw plot
\draw[domain=0.1:1.44,red,->,thick,samples=400]  plot (\x,\x^3 );% draw plot
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

(max about 1.44 instead of 2), you can see the arrowhead.

[image]

Comment: Removed braces; still no arrow.

Comment: @crmdgn Please see an addidional remark.

Comment: Found it. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use [`pgfplots`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/pgfplots) (which is based on [`tikz`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/tikz)) for this purpose

[image: screenshot]

Here's some code to get you started- see the documentation and [questions tagged with `pgfplots`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pgfplots) on this site for more details.

```
% arara: pdflatex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

% set the arrows as stealth fighters
\tikzset{>=stealth}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    xmin=0,xmax=4,
    ymin=0,ymax=3,
    axis x line=middle,
    axis y line=middle,
    ]
    \addplot[->,domain=0:1.4,samples=100] expression {x^3};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A recommended solution with PSTricks just for fun.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-2,-4)(3,4)
\psplot[algebraic,linecolor=blue,arrows=->]{-1.5}{1.5}{x^3}
\psaxes[linecolor=gray]{->}(0,0)(-2,-3.5)(2.5,3.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The `\psaxes` can be drawn first to make the graph on the top.